# How to state "there exists none, or one and only one..."?

Tags: notation, article-writing

As the title suggest, I'm trying to express that there is no (e.g., $x$), or if there is any, there will be one and only one. 
Is the following a formal/valid writing?

$$\nexists \lor \exists! x \quad \text{bla bla}$$

If no, what would be the proper way of stating this?

Comment: Quite right... You have to use a *predicate* to pick up the "class" of objects satisying the condition: $\lnot \exists x Px \lor \exists ! x Px$.

Comment: Why not just use words?

Comment: "There exists *at most one* $x$ such that ..."

Comment: @Dave I will! But I also like to have formal version. For the written one I will use the nice suggestion by Rahul

Answer (score 3):

If we want to say "There exists either exactly one, or no $x$ such that $P(x)$", then I think the most elegant way to say it is to rethink a little how we say what we want to say. I propose
$$
\forall x, y\,(P(x)\land P(y)\to x = y)
$$
The way to read this is that if you ever find yourself in a situation where you have two such elements, they are really one and the same.